# Computing a sparse subset of the outer sum of two (dense) vectors efficiently in numpy/scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

Let's say I have two dense vectors a and b in R^n. I am trying to compute the following matrix S defined as

S[i,j] = a[i]+b[j] for (i,j) in P,

S[i,j] = 0 otherwise,

where P is a sparse subset in [0, ..., n]^2. Now, of course I can compute the full outer product and then use the sparse subset P to form S, but I would like to know if there is a way to compute the entries of S only if they are needed, i.e. if there is a way to feed the set P before the entries are actually computed, to avoid computing n^2 sums. I tried looking for solutions to this problem but did not find anything.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Translate this into `numpy` code, with small sample `a`, `b` and `P`.  If these are normal `numpy` arrays, including 0/1 values for `P`, `(a[:,None]+b)*P` is likely to be fastest, since it makes maximum use of compiled numpy methods.  If `P` is already a `csr` sparse matrix, we might be able to improve on that (provided it is sparse enough).

Comment: I think what you need is to look at Python generators, Iterators and yield. This aspect of Pythion allows you to set up a placeholder for the results of a calculation but the actual calculation is not done until the value is being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty easy if P is sparse.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import scipy.sparse as sps
>>> v1 = np.random.rand(10)
>>> v2 = np.random.rand(10)
>>> P = sps.csr_matrix(np.random.rand(10,10) < 0.1)

>>> P
<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.bool_'>'
    with 20 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Now just get the non-zero indices and index your vectors with them:

```
>>> v1_idx, v2_idx = P.nonzero()
>>> OP = sps.csr_matrix((v1[v1_idx] + v2[v2_idx], (v1_idx, v2_idx)), shape=P.shape)
```

This gets you a sparse matrix filled with only the values you need from your vectors

```
>>> OP
<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 20 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```